# How would you practically measure the volume of a matzah?

Tags: passover, shiurim-measurements, matzah

So assuming a Kezayit is measured as volume, how would one calculate the volume of a matzah? Water displacement probably wouldn’t work, because it’ll get soggy!

Comment: What's wrong with soggy

Comment: @DoubleAA Sogginess could include some amount of water getting absorbed into the original volume of the matza, reducing the apparent displacement.

Comment: I had a couple of ideas, such as wrapping the matzah in Saran wrap or maybe using thin couscous instead of water. Not sure if it would be scientifically sound though.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Into the original volume of the matza? Does wheat go into solution? In its airspace maybe.

Comment: What's wrong with crushing it up in a food processor and pouring the fluid (powder) into a beaker?

Comment: You don't have to use water. Use oil instead. Also, @DoubleAA's suggestion is good. There used to be a measuring cup graduated in the shiurim for just this purpose.

Comment: or use the data on specific gravity [here](https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/food-weight-to-volume/substance/matzah-blank-meal-coma-and-blank-upc-column--blank-840762039951) and just weigh it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Crushing it up might lower the volume due to the space in a matzah. Although it’s probably a miniscule difference.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I want something to be able to demonstrate, because the halachic literature (like the Ohr Letziyon) say 20g=27cc by matzah. Based on that resource it’ll be closer to 15g.

Comment: @147zcbm So does chewing it

Comment: @DoubleAA, your argument makes sense, but all of us seem to have heard the opposite. Don't you count the air spaces in bread toward a kezais?

Answer (score 3):

Not a problem! Rav Moshe Heinemann shlit"a is said to have laminated one, then measured its displacement in water.

Comment: Does anyone know if Staples laminates matzahs?

Comment: @147zcbm You could try. But I assumed that RMH just sprayed it with plastic. However, I think it would lead to problems at the seder, when you try to break it in half.

Comment: You may know that there are numerous stories about Rav Heinemann's crazy imagination. Ask someone about the matzo baking and the windshield wipers.

Comment: I've heard this too. I think he sprayed it with something to make it non-absorbent, not actual plastic.

Answer (score 1):

One Rav I know breaks the matzos into small pieces and then stacks them, so he can roughly compare the matzah stack to an egg.

Comment: This seems irresponsibily imprecise

Comment: You don't need to measure it like a scientist in a lab. Besides, you can err on the side of caution.

Comment: I agree but there's a few kilometers between this and scientists. Maybe not parsecs, but kilometers.

Comment: In addition, there are disagreements as to size of k'zayis. That we eat two of the Noda Biyehuda's k'zeisim is really only a chumra, because the requirement for two k'zeisim is midrabbanan.

Comment: Ha, I didn't even catch that you wrote egg. Ok sure, compare roughly to a modern egg :)